# retrieve most recent records

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bit of mysql query brain freeze. I need to retrieve the latest record from a table, grouped by a second column. Something like this:

```
SELECT ca.id, ca.activity_date, cat.contact_id as cid
FROM activity ca
JOIN activity_target cat
  ON ca.id = cat.activity_id
WHERE ca.activity_type_id = 44
GROUP BY cid
ORDER BY activity_date DESC
```

...except that I need the most recent record (using activity_date) **within** the group by (the order by is performed after the group). I tried using HAVING activity_date = max(activity_date) but that doesn't work.

Comment: Which table does `contact_id` belong to?

Comment: I edited to specify the source of the fields.

Comment: What is the Primary Key of `activity_target`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this:

```
SELECT ca.id, ca.activity_date, cat.contact_id as cid
FROM activity ca
JOIN activity_target cat
  ON ca.id = cat.activity_id
WHERE ca.activity_type_id = 44
    and ca.id = (SELECT id from activity a
            join activity_target t on a.id = t.activity_id
        WHERE t.contact_id = cat.contact_id
        ORDER BY activity_date DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY activity_date DESC
```

I can't say for sure without looking at your schema, and I'm guessing a bit with the differences between MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: It's the correlation that is the problem. Unless I'm missing something, I think that just puts me in the same hole.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ca.id, ca.activity_date, cat.contact_id AS cid
FROM activity ca
  JOIN activity_target cat
    ON ca.id = cat.activity_id
  JOIN 
      ( SELECT t.contact_id
             , MAX(a.activity_date) AS activity_date 
        FROM activity a
          JOIN activity_target t 
            ON a.id = t.activity_id
        WHERE a.activity_type_id = 44
        GROUP BY t.contact_id 
      ) AS grp
    ON  grp.contact_id = cat.contact_id
    AND grp.activity_date = ca.activity_date
WHERE ca.activity_type_id = 44
ORDER BY ca.activity_date DESC
```